# What is a runtime complexity of this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, data-structures, big-o

I would like to know how fast is `SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com'`
is this O(1) or O(n)?

how does sql search for a particular row?

Comment: If there is a unique index on `email` then it's pretty much O(1). If there is no index at all, it's O(n)

Comment: The runtime complexity of this SQL query is O(log n), as SQL uses binary search to find the desired row. This means that the time it takes to execute the query is proportional to the logarithm of the number of rows in the user_table.

Comment: does sql use Map data structure to sort the data?

Comment: There is essentially no difference between `INDEX(email)` and `UNIQUE(email)`  The latter stops a simple scan after 1 row; the former will scan for multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no index on "email" column, the search complexity is **O(N)**.

If there was hash-based index on an "email" column, then the search could be performed in **O(1)**.

However in real DB engines the indices are usually tree-based (as they enable quick search not for equality only, but also for "greater/less than" conditions).
For binary trees the search complexity is **O(log N)** so in most cases index on "email" column results in this.

Comment: you need to add worst case to O(N), also a unique index would also have O(1)

Comment: For B-trees (which are used by default in most engines) the worst case search complexity is still O(log N).

Comment: today all databases use  b+-trees, as they are more efficient and reduce the search depth , but ib Uni you learn that O(N) is the worst case, as the element could be at the highest level and give a result with O(1) even with millions of rows

Comment: The access path to an entry in a B-Tree index is pretty much independent of the number of rows in the table (or index). So it's not O(log n)

Comment: The log is quite trivial in BTrees -- 3 for a million rows; 6 for a trillion rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - What!  There is a tree in a BTree.  There really is a logN component.  However, as I say in my Comment above, it is insignificant.  (I ignore it when analyzing MySQL queries.)